# Change of an image src in JS in code not apply in website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm actually working on a web application. I encountered a problem that I did not think I could meet. I change the src of an image in my JS file (because I use the JS to generate tags useful to the ajax: example -> `html += (``))`. And the change does not apply to the site, although I do a search on all my files, I do not find the path that is indicated when I check with the toolbox development on the site.

This is my js code line who generate the image :

```
html += ('<td class="dropdownHolder" >' + generateDropdownList('OTPsPour' + id, listeNomSites, listeIdSites, optionsChecked, 'tai'+id, '/Pointage_sgc_2016/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG', 'Assignation de sites', "optionssites") + '</td>');
```

And on the website it appear like this :

```
<img src="/Pointage/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG" alt="+" title="Assignation de sites">
```

I promise you I check all my files 100 times to see if I have one path like /Pointage/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG but they are all like /Pointage_sgc_2016/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG

I searched on internet in vain, if anyone can help me.

```
 function generateDropdownList(id, optionsTexte, optionsValeur, optionsChecked, formID, imgSource, imgTitle, options = "options"){

imgSource = (typeof imgSource !== 'undefined')?(imgSource):('/Pointage_sgc_2016/Ressources/Images/ic_view_list_white_24px.svg');
imgTitle = (typeof imgTitle !== 'undefined')?(imgTitle):('Plus d\'options');

var html = '';
html += '<dl id="' + id + '" class="Admin-GestionDonnees-DropdownList noSelection">';
html += '<dt onclick="slideDownList(\'' + id + '\')">';
html += '<span class="hint"><img src="' + imgSource + '" alt="+" title="' + imgTitle +'"></span>';
html += '</dt>';
html += '<dd>';
html += '<ul>';

for (var i = 0; i < optionsTexte.length; i++) {
    html += '<li><input type="checkbox"';

    if (optionsChecked[i]) {
        html += ('checked="checked"');
    }

    html +=  ('form="' + formID + '" name="'+ options +'[]" value="' + optionsValeur[i] + '" disabled=\"disabled\" /><span>' + optionsTexte[i] + '</span></li>');
}

html += '</ul>';
html += '</dd>';
html += '</dl>';

return html;
}
```

If i search in all my file Capture.PNG, to check where it appears, i obtain this:

Searching 252 files for "Capture.PNG"

\frso33-001sv001\www$\Pointage_sgc_2016\Administration\vue\scripts\gestionMachines.js:

> 221:            html += ('' +
>   generateDropdownList('OTPsPour' + id, listeNomSites, listeIdSites,
>   optionsChecked4, 'mac'+id,
>   '/Pointage_sgc_2016/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG', 'Assignation de
>   sites', "optionssites") + '');

\frso33-001sv001\www$\Pointage_sgc_2016\Administration\vue\scripts\gestionOTP.js:

> 245:             html += ('' +
>   generateDropdownList('OTPsPours' + id, listeNomSites, listeIdSites,
>   optionsChecked2, 'tai'+id,
>   '/Pointage_sgc_2016/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG', 'Assignation de
>   sites', "optionssites") + '');

\frso33-001sv001\www$\Pointage_sgc_2016\Administration\vue\scripts\gestionTachesInstallations.js:

> 211:            html += ('' +
>   generateDropdownList('OTPsPour' + id, listeNomSites, listeIdSites,
>   optionsChecked, 'tai'+id,
>   '/Pointage_sgc_2016/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG', 'Assignation de
>   sites', "optionssites") + '');

3 matches across 3 files

Comment: What does the code for the function `generateDropdownList` actually do. Could you include it here please?

Comment: what does the image do once it's inserted?

Comment: @Brian i have an image broke

Comment: @olly_uk i add it :)

Comment: well, i know you specifically said that the image is there, but that's a 404 :/ if you inspect the img tag with your browser, you can see the absolute path of the image, maybe something's wrong

Comment: @Brian it's a close application, not on internet, just on the society network, that's why the 404. I check the absolute path with the browser and that : /Pointage/Ressources/Images/Capture.PNG, but the problem is i have not a path like this in my files, i do a ctrl shift f to search everywhere but nothing like Pointage/ just path like Pointage_sgc_2016.

Comment: Could the link be altered elsewhere?

Comment: you function code does not change the src passed to it so you must have other code somewhere that is changing the img src after it is create using your generateDropdownList function. i tested it here : https://jsfiddle.net/w3cL3dos/

Comment: @MauricePerry nop i check everywhere, there is just the function generatedropdrownlist who use this path. One thing is weird i do the same with same function in every others files and its works ...

Comment: @olly_uk thanks for testing, but nothing else change the path, the function change it if it doesn't exist. If exist, the function keep the path Pointage_sgc_2016. The weird thing is really that i have nothing in my code with Pointage/ like path, i search many times.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to really help as others have pointed out, however as a side note "ressources" is spelled "resources". Normally i wouldn't say anything, but since we're talking about a path not being resolved that could be the issue.

Comment: @zfrisch in French it spells like this

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realize

Comment: @zfrisch i can put here the files you want to help ! I just don't know why is this not work, and i don't think it comes from elsewhere